# Jquery (“.selector li:last-child”) vs (“.selector > li:last-child”)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why is (“.mylist li:last-child”) not working,
but (“.mylist > li:last-child”) give the right result and what exactly is the difference?

I àm wondering because my script was working for some time...

```
<ul class="mylist ">
    <li id="1">a</li>
    <li id="2">b</li>
    <li id="3">c</li>
    <li id="4">d</li>
</ul>

var $LastpostID = $('.mylist li:last').attr('id')
console.log ($LastpostID)
result undefined


var $LastpostID = $('.mylist > li:last').attr('id')
console.log ($LastpostID)
result 4
```

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/zrv4anc4/

Comment: The first selects all descendants that match `li:last`, the second selects only immediate descendants (children) that match `li:last`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` means "direct child of": only nodes that are direct children are selected.

While a `space` means "any descendant of": direct children and children of those children could be selected.

**but in your case both should work as same.**